# Add content to opened window before load

Tags: javascript, windows

My code for opening new window in JS.

```
var myWindow = window.open();
myWindow.document.write('html');
```

Is it possible to write content to document before window loads? I would like to add entire html to document, including some JS code. I tried concatenating html code but it didn't go throught even with my code editor.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the entire document before opening it, but the way you do it is as a *data URI* or an *Object URL* pointing to a *Blob*, for example

```
// Blob method, most modern, almost no restrictions other than legacy browser support
function genWindow(code) {
    var b = new Blob([code], {type: 'text/html'}),
        uri = URL.createObjectURL(b),
        wind = window.open(uri, '_blank');
    URL.revokeObjectURL(uri); // and cleanup
    return wind;
}
genWindow('\
<!doctype html>\n\
<html>\n\
    <head>\n\
        <title>Hello World!</title>\n\
    </head>\n\
    <body>\n\
        <span>Foobar</span>\n\
    </body>\n\
</html>\n\
');
```

Or the other method I mentioned;

```
// data URI method, more restricted (e.g. file size) but will work in older browsers
function genWindow2(code) {
    return window.open('data:text/html,' + window.encodeURIComponent(code), '_blank');
}
genWindow2('\
<!doctype html>\n\
<html>\n\
    <head>\n\
        <title>Hello World!</title>\n\
    </head>\n\
    <body>\n\
        <span>Fizzbuzz</span>\n\
    </body>\n\
</html>\n\
');
```